Help installing Ubuntu 24.04 on previous Ubuntu partition on Dell XPS 15
I did sudo update to upgrade and then I did in place 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade using the proper tool which I forget the name of at the moment. And then when it tried to boot it wouldn't boot past a certain point just locked up. I tried to install 24.04 externally on top of that partition it didn't work. Then took the partition and just reformatted it using GParted and I still couldn't get the installer to choose that partition. During the install it will highlighted that line, but it doesn't checkmark the box and it doesn't remove the grayout on the Next button.
Installation halt point:

GParted of drive:

UEFI:


I think you need to click on the partition where you want to install Ubuntu 24.04 and click on the "Change" button to change the properties of that partition.
In the Change partition dialog box, select the mountpoint of this partition to be "/", i.e., the root directory. Once there is a partition in the list that can serve as root, the Next button becomes active.

I'm sixty miles from my computer. I will try that tomorrow, Wednesday, the 23rd of Oct ,2024
